# DATEDIFF in DDMMYYY Format in SQL ( Default seem to be yyyymmdd) -

Tags: sql

I have below logic which returns 3 months ago from today and day will always be 15. So if you run it for October, it will return 15 and OCT - 3 months will be July. So you will get July 15.

```
select  CONVERT(char,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-3, 0) + 14,23);
```

However, the format will be YYYY-MM-DD such as 2022-07-15

I tried everything but I need advise as my required format is  DD/MM/YYYY

So how will I amend above so it returns date as 15/07/2022

Comment: Which dbms are you using? DATEADD and DATEDIFF are product specific functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use date style 103 or 105 rather than 23...

```
select 
  CONVERT(char,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-3, 0) + 14,103) as style_103, 
  CONVERT(char,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-3, 0) + 14,105) as style_105, 
  CONVERT(char,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-3, 0) + 14,23) as style_23
```

Output:

```
style_103   style_105   style_23
15/07/2022  15-07-2022  2022-07-15
```